# DateTime check in permissions Hyperledger fabric

Tags: javascript, function, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to check if I can include some conditions (complex ones) in the permission.acl file in the composer Hyperledger fabric.

I wanted to know two things. Following is the cto component of the asset:

```
asset Document identified by documentId {
  o String documentId
  o String value
  o DocumentType type
  o String owner
  o String reviewer optional
  o String status
  o String mediatype
  o DateTime validFrom
  o DateTime validTo
}

rule nurseCanViewDocumentsWithinExpiry {
    description: "Allow all participants full access to their assets"
    participant(p): "org.apatics.net.Participants"
    operation: READ
    resource(r): "org.apatics.net.Document"
    condition: ##HOW TO GIVE THE FUNCTION HERE##
    action: ALLOW
}
```

1) Can I include some complex conditions? Through the function? I tried a function as follows:

```
  function (r){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (new Date() > r.validTo && r.reviewer == p.participantId && p.type == "test")
      return true
    else
      return false
  }
```

The above function always returns true?

2) Will the Date check work here? Would new Date() really give me the current date and time?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to making this work :-)

Starting with the Basic Sample Network (namespace `org.example.basic`) I added this Asset:

```
asset MedDocument identified by documentId {
 o String documentId 
 o String value
 o String type
 o String owner
 o Boolean reviewer optional
 o String status
 o String mediatype
 o DateTime validFrom
 o DateTime validTo
}
```

I created this test data:

```
{
 "$class": "org.example.basic.MedDocument",
 "documentId": "01",
 "value": "Treatment Plan",
 "type": "TP",
 "owner": "Dr02",
 "reviewer": true,
 "status": "live",
 "mediatype": "paper",
 "validFrom": "2018-10-01T09:03:22.171Z",
 "validTo": "2018-10-10T09:03:22.171Z",
}
{
 "$class": "org.example.basic.MedDocument",
 "documentId": "02",
 "value": "Treatment Plan",
 "type": "TP",
 "owner": "Dr02",
 "reviewer": true,
 "status": "live",
 "mediatype": "paper",
 "validFrom": "2018-10-11T09:03:22.171Z",
 "validTo": "2018-10-20T09:03:22.171Z",
```

}

I added this ACL Rule - and **removed the rule** `EverybodyCanReadEverything` !

```
rule nurseCanViewDocumentsWithinExpiry {
 description: "Allow all participants full access to their assets"
 participant(p): "org.example.basic.SampleParticipant"
 operation: READ
 resource(r): "org.example.basic.MedDocument"
 condition: (testRange(r, p))
 action: ALLOW
}
```

I added this function to my JS logic:

```
/**
 * Test that the specified asset (medical doc) is within range.
 * @param {Resource} asset The asset.
 * @param {Resource} participant The participant.
 * @return {boolean} True if yes, false if no.
 */
function testRange(asset, participant) {

 var current=new Date();

 return ((current > asset.validFrom) && (current < asset.validTo));

}
```

I created a new SampleParticipant and issued a new ID.  The Result (run on 2nd October!) was that I could see the first MedDocument, but not the second.

I am passing the asset (MedDocument) into the script function, and also passing the Participant.  I don't use the participant, but left it there as you may need it.)